# NodeJS conditional request before the real request

Tags: node.js, coffeescript

In my code I have to login a user with username and password. But if the user sends his e-mail instead of his username, I have to resolve it with another request.

This is what the code looks like:

```
exports.auth = (request, response, next) ->
  username = request.body.username
  if request.body.email
      users.findByEmail request.body.email, (error, result) ->
          return next new InternalServerError(error) if error
          username = result[0].username
          auth.auth username, request.body.password, (error, result) ->
              return next new InternalServerError(error) if error
              response.json responseData
  else
      auth.auth username, request.body.password, (error, result) ->
          return next new InternalServerError(error) if error
          response.json responseData
```

As you can see there are 3 duplicate lines.

Does anyone know a good code style do make this better? Maybe with Promises? Async Waterfall? Waitfor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Promises would make sense to me, but first step would be to extract stuff into functions.

You don't really *need* promises for this, though. Here's one way to just do it with plain callbacks:

```
exports.auth = (request, response, next) ->
  getUsername = (request, cb) ->
    email = request.body.email
    return cb null, request.body.username unless email

    users.findByEmail email, (error, result) ->
      return cb new InternalServerError(error) if error
      cb null, result[0].username

  getUsername (err, username) ->
    return next err if err
    auth.auth username, request.body.password, (err, json) ->
      return next err if err
      response.json json
```